# Создание текстовых каналов ботом по команде от привелигированных пользователей

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно, чтобы указанные мной привелигированные пользователи могли выполнить команду, по которой бот создавал бы множество текстовых каналов. Код показать не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код, который будет при команде `test` создавать текстовые каналы

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
id = '123456789 456789123 456789123'

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if not str(ctx.author.id) in id:
        return
    for _ in range(100):
        guild = ctx.guild
        await guild.create_text_channel('New Text Channel')

client.run('token')
```